# Superfullcite with style=alphabetic

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing, marginnote

I am using `\superfullcite{}` explained [here](http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/). As I understand it (which is not much I'm afraid), it is basically a `\footfullcite{}` that only appears once as a footnote, even if cited several times.
I like this very much, since it allows me (using `\AtEveryCiteKey{\clearfield{...}}`) to put (small) citations into the footer (or margin for tufte) and have the (complete, long) citation at the end.

However, it uses `numeric-comp`, and I'd rather have the links to my citations be `[XYZ99]` like this, (I guess that would be `alphabetic`)
This way,there exists no implied numerical order, which gets messed up upon sorting alphabetically. But if a person reads only the bibliography.

I'm not really sure how to go about this.
What is missing is basically only a change of labels, however I'm unsure how to do this.

- Keep using `numeric-comp` and `sorting=true` and somehow modify labels?
- Start using `alphabetic` and try to get `\superfullcite{}` to work?

A MWE would be this one

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%\documentclass[a4paper, nobib, notoc, symmetric, marginals=raggedouter, justified]{tufte-book} % 
%\morefloats
%\morefloats
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyphenat} 
\usepackage[american]{babel}


\usepackage[block=nbpar, firstinits=false, backref=true, maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=99,  isbn=false, doi=false, url=false, eprint=false, style=numeric-comp, backend=biber, sorting=none, citetracker=true, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
%%=====
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\notefullcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{notefullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{notefullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
       \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}.}}}


% Declare superfullcite and remap it to cite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfullcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
\makeatother

%\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\superfullcite{#1}} %remap \superfullcite to \cite



\begin{document}
Some filler text \notefullcite{cotton}, then some more text
\notefullcite{hammond}. Perhaps some more text and the same
citation again \notefullcite{hammond}. Yet another one
\notefullcite{knuth:ct:a}. Now all again
\notefullcite{cotton,hammond,knuth:ct:a}.

Some filler text,\superfullcite{augustine} then some more
text.\superfullcite{companion} Perhaps some more text and the
same citation again.\superfullcite{companion} Yet another
one.\superfullcite{kastenholz} Now all
again.\superfullcite{augustine,companion,kastenholz}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

As you can see I use `sorting=none` but I cannot change the style to alphabetic, since the `cite:init` and similar macros do not work. Could someone elaborate on what these do? Seaching the biblatex documentation turns up 0 results.

Comment: You can use `sorting=none` to have the numeric labels in cite-order. What I fear with this approach is that it might be quite hard to identify which footnote goes with which alphabetic label in the end and in repeated citations. I could imagine a cite command that always prints the alphabetic label, but on the first cite also adds a footnote with the full citation.

Comment: I already use `sorting=none`, however there are no alphabetic labels, since the MWE as is will not compile for `style=alphabetic`. I could imagine the exact same cite command as well, in fact that's more or less what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define a new command `\sfcite` that prints the standard citation and adds a `\footfullcite`, i.e. a footnote with the full bibliographic entry, on the first occurrence of a citation.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifciteseen
     {}
     {\footfullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

(The definition above is designed to work with `alphabetic`, but if you delete the `[\mkbibbrackets]` it works with a lot of the other standard styles. The basic idea is to add the `\ifciteseen{}{\footfullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}}` block after `\usebibmacro{cite}` in the definition.)

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber,citetracker=constrict]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifciteseen
     {}
     {\footfullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
Lorem \sfcite{wilde} ipsum \sfcite{cicero} dolor \sfcite{wilde} sit
\sfcite{geer} amet \sfcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}.

Cite again \sfcite{geer} and \sfcite{cicero}.
\end{document}
```

[image]